# Dficuldade para tratar uma lista com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma dificuldade de tratar um lista pelo javascript gostaria de uma dica ou ajuda se possível

esse é o erro que estou tomando

> Array [ "AC.FIXA" ]  cadastro:280:4
>   ReferenceError: $ is not defined[Learn More]  cadastro:282:4
>   String vazia passada para getElementById(). cadastro
>   String vazia passada para getElementById(). cadastro

e meu javascript

```
<script>
    listaProjeto = "${usuarioBean.listaNomeProjeto}";

    listaProjeto = listaProjeto.replace("[", "")
    listaProjeto = listaProjeto.replace("]", "")
    var teste = listaProjeto.split(",");
    console.log(teste)

    $.each(teste, function(index, value) {
        alert(index + ": " + value);
    });
</script>
```

pelo que li por cima diz que meu jQuery não esta instalado, mas está tudo correto.

Comment: Cadê a parte que você referencia o jQuery na página?

Comment: pelo codigo que voce postou o erro nao esta acontecendo nessa parte, porque nao tem nenhum getElementByID no seu codigo mas o erro vem dali (e tb acho que o jQuery nao foi referenciado)

Comment: aqui esta o código acima com a referencia do jQuery                            <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

  <script>
   listaProjeto = "${usuarioBean.listaNomeProjeto}";

   listaProjeto = listaProjeto.replace("[", "")
   listaProjeto = listaProjeto.replace("]", "")
   var teste = listaProjeto.split(",");
   console.log(teste)

   $.each(teste, function(index, value) {
    alert(index + ": " + value);
   });
  </script>

Comment: se o jquery esta instalado corretamente você pode não ter referenciado ele no seu HTML por exemplo, algo assim `<script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>`

Comment: pois é cara mais eu referenciei ele na pagina normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, verifica os `;` no final das linhas.

Seguindo, acrescenta o jQuery logo acima do teu script e verifica se o erro persiste, assim:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
listaProjeto = "${usuarioBean.listaNomeProjeto}";

listaProjeto = listaProjeto.replace("[", ""); // <- Ponto e virgula
```

Comment: então coloquei os ; e nada mudou e já estava referenciado acima do código.

Comment: Deixa eu tentar te ajudar então, muda tua pergunta exibindo exatamente onde tu referenciou o jQuery e qual versão tu está usando. E para já deixarmos isso pra trás, abaixo de `listaProjeto = "${usuarioBean.listaNomeProjeto}";` coloca `console.log(listaProjeto);` para validarmos o conteúdo da tua variável.